# How to write a Jasmine test for a webpage that has HTML and JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, bdd, jasmine

Of the material I read on Jasmine, they test only a `.js` file.  But what if the test is on a webpage, say, with the code:

try.html:

```
<input id="the-input"></input>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#the-input").focus(function() {
        $(this).css("background", "#ff9");
    });

    $("#the-input").blur(function() {
        $(this).css("background", "#cff");
    });  

</script>
```

which is just to say, if the user clicks on (or tab to) the input box, make the box's background yellow, and when focus out, then make it light blue.  In such case, how do we test the above behavior in the .html file?  (where should this html file be -- can it be any where outside of the Jasmine lib file and SpecRunner.html, and how does the SpecRunner.html include it somehow to test the page?

A jsfiddle is in:  http://jsfiddle.net/MspUF/

**Update:** it is fine to separate the HTML content and the JavaScript code, but still, what ARE THE SPECIFICS as to be able to test it.

Answer (score 6):

After some research, I found a simple way to test JavaScript together with HTML, CSS, and JSON data.  It is [Jasmine-jQuery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) and those are called HTML fixtures, etc.  So not a full, self-contained page, but possibly enough to tell your widgets works fine if the mouse is over it, or what should happen if a user clicks on something. (by using jQuery `.mouseover()` or `.click()`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

It is generally, best practice to move scripts to external `js` files in web browsers as well.

You can move your code to a `.js` file and then include it in your HTML by doing:

```
<script src='myfile.js'>
```

Which will include it, this will allow you to easily use Jasmine to test the file. You can mock your DOM for unit testing outside the DOM.

If you need general testing instead of unit testing, I suggest something like [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) that would actually simulate a browser and enable you to test the complete user experience. (Other good alternatives include Selenium which I had success with)

Also, [here is a nice article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff452703.aspx)  about testing jQuery with QUnit.

Comment: you mean, if my HTML file is complicated, such as one having 200 or 500 lines, then I have to mock them all up instead of using the HTML file as is?  (and how to "mock it up"?)  What I need to test is, when the user clicks on it, the background does change

Comment: In that case Jasmine alone is probably not the right tool for you, check out PhantomJS or Selenium, PhantomJS works with Jasmine, it simulates a web browser and lets you test your code, it sounds like Exactly what you need.

Comment: PhantomJS will be all terminal based?  At work, my coworker actually set it all up so that if there are 20 HTML files all using various `.js` files, then all 20 HTML files can be tested, all inside Chrome or Safari... and the report for all 20 HTML files actually shows up as 1 single page that looks just like `SpecRunner.html`.  I can't ask him how it is done until a couple of days later

Comment: Yes, with PhantomJS testing will be just like running any other Jasmine test. If you would like to test inside the browser, you can read the article I linked to or check out Selenium.